# OpenSSL is erroring in Rails but not Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

When trying to connect via SSL in Rails, we get the error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

There are a number of other StackOverflow articles that cover the same error but the symptom that we are experiencing is quite different.

When we issue a test command in Ruby, it works, but when we issue the same command booted into a Rails environment, we get the above error.

Here is sample with output (as recommended by bundler.io: https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#troubleshooting-certificate-errors)

ruby:

```
oot@376dd015bcee:/usr/src/app# ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems:       2.7.7
Bundler:        1.16.6
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
Loaded version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /usr/lib/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       success ✅
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      success ✅
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: success ✅

Hooray! This Ruby can connect to rubygems.org. You are all set to use Bundler and RubyGems. 
(eval):136: warning: constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS is deprecated
```

rails:

```
root@376dd015bcee:/usr/src/app# RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails r 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81)
no value for ELK DNS -
Expected string default value for '--serializer'; got true (boolean)
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems:       2.7.7
Bundler:        1.16.6
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
Loaded version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /usr/lib/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       success ✅
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      success ✅
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: failed  ❌

Unfortunately, this Ruby can't connect to rubygems.org. 
Your Ruby can't connect to rubygems.org because you are missing the certificate files OpenSSL needs to verify you are connecting to the genuine rubygems.org servers.
```

A couple of other points:

1. This is a standard ruby docker container with Amazon Linux AMI
2. The SSL_CERT_FILE `/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem` does not exist, however, SSL_CERT_DIR does exist and has all the requisite certs in it.

Why would this work for Ruby but not for Rails?